# Add JS function on dynamically called element(html) fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I have an `eventClick` function on jQuery fullcalendar,

The idea is that when I click on my event it opens a modal box and from there I can delete the event.

Also I have made deleting events with dropping it on trash, but when I move the event outside fullcalendar content it hides from me, I have tried to change `fc-view : overflow:visible;` but nothing helped for that, that's why I'm trying to make delete after opening modal box.

```
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var modal = 
            '<div class="modal fade">'+
                '<div class="modal-dialog">'+                     
                    '<div class="modal-content">'+
                        '<div class="modal-header">'+
                            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+
                            '<h4 class="modal-title">'+ calEvent.title +'</h4>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="modal-body">'+
                           '<form class="separate-sections" method="post">'+
                            '<div class="form-group input-append calendar_time_pick">'+
                                '<div class="input-group addon-left" onclick="showdate()">'+
                                    '<span class="input-group-addon add-on">'+
                                        '<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-time"></i>'+
                                    '</span>'+
                                    '<input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss" type="text" name="date" placeholder="Time" ></input>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div>'+
                                '<button class="btn btn-blue btn-block" >Save<i class="icon-save"></i></button>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</form>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                            '<button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                            '<button type="button" onclick="deleteEvent('+calEvent.id+')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        $(modal).modal('show');
     },
```

And i have delete function

```
var deleteEvent = function (id) {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
  }
```

But this doesn't work, because when all JS is loaded, the modal isn't showed and that's why it can't run that function afterwards.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteEvent is not defined`

Comment: do you want to show the event details in pop up? you could refer this http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar-with-ui-modal-dialog/

Comment: I want to make clickable button which triggers to delete event!

Comment: did you mean click on the event the pop up will be show and while pressing on the delete button it should delete. right?

Comment: come to this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers